# What is the state space of this markov chain?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Consider a system where two persons sit at a table and share three books. At any point in time both are reading a book, and one book is left on the table. When a person finishes reading his/her current book, he/she swaps it with the book on the table and starts reading. Reading times are exponentially distributed, denote by bi,j the average time for person i to read book j.

```
Let b = [1 2 4]
        [5 1 2]
```

**What is the state space of this markov chain and how can i construct the rate matrix Q ?**

I got this exercise from my lecture notes and somehow find the state space confusing since it is a continuous time markov chain.

These are the possible states i could think of :

Person i1 and i2, Book A,B,C

```
i1,A
i1,B
i1,C
i2,A
i2,B
i2,C
```

But how can i represent this graphically ? I tried but each user has a separate markov chain(reducible) which i doubt is correct. I think from there constructing the rate matrix based on the rates on matrix b should be ok.

Comment: I don't think each user has a separate Markov chain, because each user has influence on the book the other one will read next. I think the state space consists of the following ordered pairs with distinct elements: (A,B), (A,C), (B,A), (B,C), (C,A), (C,B). Here, the first element is the book currently read by person i1, and the second element is the book currently read by person i2. All possible transitions can be described as follows. Let (X,Y,Z) be any permutation of (A,B,C). Then (X,Y)->(Z,Y) and (X,Y)->(X,Z) are valid transitions.

Comment: @jflipp thanks for the response i thought as much but a little confused with the pairs and transitions you made. Can you show me for example a transition of where the second user reads the third book ?

Comment: Say, the current state is (A,B), i.e. the first user is reading book A, and the second user is reading book B, book C is on the table. Then, the second user finishes book B and picks up book C. So the next state is (A,C). Using the description from my previous comment, the situation described here corresponds to the permutation (A,B,C) of (A,B,C) and the transition (X,Y)->(X,Z).

Comment: @jflipp thanks, please reply as an answer.